# ghost phpmyadmin folder?

Tags: linux, php, centos

I have a server runing CentOS6. i installed phpmyadmin and the rest with this tutorial -

> http://www.kdweb.co.uk/blog/installing-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-centos-6-php-memcache-drupal-6-memcache-api

After instalation..i cant find the phpmyadmin in my /var/www/html..i tried restarting httpd...tried rebooting the server and tried 'updatedb', non seem to index the folder.

what odd is...when i go to the phpmyadmin folder in the browser it gives 'Forbidden' error. which means it is there. but i cant see it nor get there.

```
http://94.23.250.14/phpmyadmin
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you examine the contents of the package you'll see that it contains a HTTPd configuration file which aliases `/phpmyadmin` to a directory under `/usr/share`. Look in the HTTPd error log to see why you can't access it.

Comment: How can i see the logs in CentOS6?

Comment: Logs in CentOS are under `/var/log` as per the FHS.

Comment: nm. got it...this is the last entries [Sun Aug 05 21:30:09 2012] [error] [client 79.176.106.69] client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
[Sun Aug 05 21:30:09 2012] [error] [client 79.176.106.69] File does not exist: /var/www/html/favicon.ico

Comment: Any thoughts?..

Comment: Yes. Check your configuration notes to see if you've disabled access to `/usr/share` somehow.

Comment: I added the /usr/share/phpmyadmin to httpd config like so: <Directory "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin">
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: and it worked...now when i log in i get phpMyAdmin - Error
#2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Comment: That would be a separate issue.

Comment: lol sorry, the mysqld service was off..all good now. thank you buddy :)